# Canada to South America with connections in US with multiple airlines, where will I do security/baggage check?

Tags: air-travel, canada, tsa, american-airlines, westjet

I am a US passport holder (living in Canada) traveling from Canada to Ecuador with connections in the US via multiple airlines. I'm worried that some of my layovers might be a bit too tight. To help plan, I'm trying to find out when, where, and how many times I'll have to check luggage and have security checks.

This was all purchased on a single ticket through Cheap O Air.

Here's my itinerary:

Edmonton, Canada (YEG) -> Las Vegas, USA (LAS) Airline: WestJet
Departure: 8:30 AM, Arrival: 10:30 AM

-Layover time: 1:48-

Las Vegas, USA -> Miami, USA (MIA) Airline: American Airlines
Departure: 12:18 PM, Arrival: 8:07 PM

-Layover time: 1:23-

Miami, USA -> Quito, Ecuador (UIO) Airline: LATAM Airlines
Departure: 9:30PM, Arrival: 12:45Am (next day)

Questions:

Will I have to baggage check for each airline? And does that mean I have to leave the gates for each check and do security each time? If not, where and when can I expect those things to happen?

Also, I did an online chat with a Cheap O Air representative, and the he assured me that I would only need to do baggage check and security at YEG and not at my connections in the US. That sounds too good to be true to be honest and I don't know if I believe him.

Comment: Note that [WestJet has a codeshare agreement with LATAM and a baggage agreement with American](https://www.westjet.com/en-us/about-us/airline-partners), which is consistent with you not needing to re-check your bags.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert But American and LATAM don't seem to have any agreements. This is a really weird itinerary, given that both WestJet and LATAM are codeshare partners with _Delta_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct. When going *to* Ecuador, the luggage will be checked through and you will not have to leave the secure area. I have done similar Canada to Ecuador trips dozens of times.

When coming *back*, if you have the same itinerary, you will need to collect your luggage in Miami, which means exit the secure area and re-enter. You will also have to do immigration in Miami as the US entry point. Even with the faster lanes with electronic machines to do immigration for US and Canadian passport holders, this can take a while.

Comment: Follow up question: my return itinerary is different, I go to Miami, then Las Vegas, then Calgary then Edmonton. I know I'll be doing US customs in Miami but where will I do Canadian customs? Calgary or Edmonton?

Comment: Customs would be in Calgary. First point of entry is the norm for Canadian customs but I have never done that exact itinerary.

Answer (score 2):

Edmonton is a US Preclearance port, so southbound you'll pass through US immigration and customs at the airport there before you get on the WestJet flight.